# Is it possible to find the Wordpress login link from cPanel?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, cpanel, wordpress-login

Is it possible to find the wordpress login link (tipically www.domain.com/wp-login.php) if I have access in cPanel ?

Comment: What cPanel do you mean? You host cPanel or inside of you wordpress panel?

Comment: I mean host cPanel

Comment: Well that depends of you hosting service cPanel. Because many hosting service has special features to wordpress sites but others no yet. You must to check you hosting service panel configuration and check if you can enable a button, link, whatever... If you create you wordpress site using the hosting service tools, is possible to have that option.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You will find it in phpmyadmin database.